# How to make a theme default in Ubuntu 17.10?

Tags: ubuntu, gnome

I am making my own Linux distro based on Ubuntu server 17.10. I've installed Gnome, added plugins, installed new icons, etc.

Now that it looks how I want it, I want the theme it has now to be a default (It is the theme used when the user logs in for the first time), ensuring that when it is started up for the first time, it uses my theme rather than the default Ubuntu look. How do this?

Answer (score 0):

As per @ mick8985  from ubuntuforums.org [article](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1151272) 
The gnome config files can be put into a folder called /etc/skel, any new user you create will have those files in there home folder.
Make sure your customized installed theme available in /usr/share/themes and icon theme in /usr/share/icons